# add a responsive condition to a scroll function

Tags: javascript, scroll, width, conditional-statements

I use a simple script for a sticky nav header but I Wonder to know how can I add a condition for smaller screen. So here is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var aboveHeight = $('#top_menu').outerHeight();
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > aboveHeight){
            $('.menu').addClass('fixed').css('top','0').next().css('padding-top','100px');
        } 
        else {
            $('.menu').removeClass('fixed').next().css('padding-top','30px');
        }
    });
});
```

I'd like to change the value of the addClass padding-top (on the 5th line) from 100px to 30px for screen smaller then 600px width. Something like:

```
if (window.width <= 600)
```

Hope you understand my request caus my English is not very good :p Thank you all in advance for any help.

Comment: You could do this: `$('.menu').addClass('fixed').css('top','0').next().css('padding-top',window.width <= 600 ? '30px' : '100px');`

Comment: Thank's for the answer Jeff, but when I use it, my nav header stop to be sticky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store and set the padding-top value based on the window.innerWidth value like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var aboveHeight = $('#top_menu').outerHeight(),
      windowWidth = window.innerWidth,
      menuPaddingTop = '100px';

  // Add additional statements to this if needed
  if (windowWidth <= 600) {
    menuPaddingTop = '30px';
  }

  $(window).scroll(function(){
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > aboveHeight){
          $('.menu').addClass('fixed').css('top','0').next().css('padding-top', menuPaddingTop);
      } 
      else {
          $('.menu').removeClass('fixed').next().css('padding-top','30px');
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you so much Josh. It works perfectly :) Sadly, I cannot vote for your answer  caus I need more reputation point. But that's awesome, thank's again.